# Are emoji smiles also contagious?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, empathy

It is fairly common knowledge that smiles are contagious is this also true when people are exposed to ascii/emoji smiles? ie. :) , ☺ , [image]

By contagious I mean making a person feel happier and more likely to smile themselves.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** Emoji smiles are contagious just like real human smiles.

As [this study](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17470919.2013.873737?journalCode=psns20#.VLadY2TF871) suggest the brain activity observed when people look at emojis is the same when we look at real faces, and subsequently mimicry and emotion contagion follows.

> We presented 20 participants with images of upright and inverted
>   faces, emoticons and meaningless strings of characters. Emoticons
>   showed a large amplitude N170 when upright and a decrease in amplitude
>   when inverted, the opposite pattern to that shown by faces. This
>   indicates that when upright, emoticons are processed in
>   occipitotemporal sites similarly to faces due to their familiar
>   configuration.

Also, a more [general study](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/24/8788.full) for on-line expressed emotions demostrated emotion contagion similar to face to face comunication.

> We show, via a massive (N = 689,003) experiment on Facebook, that
>   emotional states can be transferred to others via emotional contagion,
>   leading people to experience the same emotions without their
>   awareness. We provide experimental evidence that emotional contagion
>   occurs without direct interaction between people (exposure to a friend
>   expressing an emotion is sufficient), and in the complete absence of
>   nonverbal cues.